Proof: $2^{n-1}(a^n-b^n)/n(a-b) \geq (a+b)^{n-1}$
If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \geq 2 $ and $a,b \geq 0 $, then $$2^{n-1}(a^n-b^n)/n(a-b) \geq (a+b)^{n-1}$$
Please kindly Notice that the left-hand side of the inequality can be factored, and the equality condition is
a=b. The left-hand side is written in this form to maintain symmetry.
I have tested n=${2,3,4,5,6}$
If n=2:
$$2^{2-1}(a^2-b^2)/2(a-b) \geq (a+b)^{2-1}$$
$$(a+b) \geq (a+b)$$
If n=3:
$$2^{3-1}(a^3-b^3)/3(a-b) \geq (a+b)^{3-1}$$
$$4(a^2 + ab +b^2) \geq 3(a+b)^{2}$$
If n=4:
$$2^{4-1}(a^4-b^4)/4(a-b) \geq (a+b)^{4-1}$$
$$2(a^2+b^2) \geq (a+b)^{2}$$
However, I can only use The Mathematical Induction to prove $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \geq 2 $. I have not found a good general way to prove it when $n \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$ with $n \geq 2 $.

Arguably you did yourself a disservice by factoring out $(a+b)$ in the even $n$ case. $\quad$ Hint: Show that $ (a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots + b^{n-1} ) / (n-1) \geq [(a+b)/2]^{n-1}$. This follows because the coefficients sum to 1, and are bunched up in the middle on the RHS so AM-GM could be made to work.

For another approach, when $a\neq b$, WLOG (why?) Let $ a = 1 + x, b = 1 - x$. Then, the inequality follows immediately by binomial expansion.

@CalvinLin Thanks so much for your comments.As far as I can get, AM-GM can not prove it. Use a=1+x, b=1-x will constraint a+b=2(This seems not fully compliant).

@
Calvin Lin Your inequality should be $$\dfrac{a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots + b^{n-1} }{n} \geq \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-1}.$$

@chrinide 1/ It can be done, just split it up much much more. 2/ The "why?" after WLOG means that you have to justify why we can do it. How would you explain it? EG If we started with $ a = 3, b = 2$, then how do we transform it and what is the $x$?

Without loss of generality we can assume that $0 \le a < b$. Applying the Hermite–Hadamard inequality to the convex function $f(x) = x^{n-1}$ gives
$$
\left( \frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-1} \le \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b x^{n-1} \, dx
= \frac{b^n-a^n}{n(b-a)} \, ,
$$
which is the desired inequality.
This works for all real exponents $n \ge 2$, not only for integral exponents. If $n > 2$ then $f$ is strictly convex, so that the inequality is strict for $a \ne b$.
The Hermite–Hadamard inequality has a simple geometric interpretation: The graph of $f$ lies above its tangent line at the point $((a+b)/2, f((a+b)/2))$, so that $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ can be estimated below by the area under that tangent line. The following visualization is taken from the french Wikipedia article about that inequality.


That is really a univeral solusion!Thanks so much!

Preamble: I did an Approach0 search and was surprised that this inequality didn't turn up, so I'm going to assume that this is novel to MSE. I think I've seen this problem long ago during training, so if it's not novel, please delete this solution.
As OP mentioned, $a = b$ leads to the equality condition. Henceforth, WLOG let $ a > b$.
Solution: Let $ a + b  = 2c$, which gives us $ a = c+x , b = c - x$ for some $ x > 0 $.
The original inequality transforms to WTS
$$ 2^{n-1} \frac{ (c+x)^{n} - (c-x)^{n} }{ n[(c+x) - (c-x)] } \geq  (2c)^{n-1} \Leftrightarrow (c+x)^{n} - (c-x)^{n}  \geq 2nxc^{n-1} $$
This is true by binomial theorem, since for $n \geq 2$ and $ x > 0$, we have
$$ (c+x)^{n} - (c-x)^{n } = 2{n \choose 1 } x^1c^{n-1} + 2 { n\choose 3 } x^3c^{n-3} + \ldots  \geq 2nxc^{n-1}.  $$
Equality holds iff $n =2 $, and for all values of $x$, hence all values of  $a, b$.
Remember to combine that with the original $ a = b$ equality condition.

Thanks so much for your detailed and great work! So I can under stand your normalize step and tranformation!

The normaliation step is just like in data-science! However, I would like to suggest that one could use more clearly normalize-transformation: $A = \frac{ 2Ka}{a+b } , B = \frac{ 2Kb}{a+b } $. This gives us $ A>B, A + B = 2K$. Then the K terms cancel out! This step like to be more easy to understand! Thanks for your great idea!

Even without normalization you can write $A^n-B^n = (c+x)^n - (c-x)^n \ge 2n c^{n-1} x$ with $c=(a+b)/2$ and $x=(a-b)/2$.

@MartinR Yes. I was overly fascinated with getting the $2^{n-1}$ term to also cancel out. I've used your substitution instead since we can combine steps.

Since you already checked a few small cases, I think we can proceed by induction as follows:
Assume the given inequality is true for $n-1$, we prove it also hold for $n$. First we state the following inequality for $ n\ge 2$:
\begin{equation} \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-1}\le\frac{a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}}{2} \tag{1} \label{meq}\end{equation}
A proof for this can be found at:A proof of fraction inequality by induction.
We reduce your inequality to the form
$$\dfrac{(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots + b^{n-1} )}{n} \geq \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-1} $$
By induction, we already had
\begin{equation}\dfrac{(a^{n-2}+a^{n-3}b+\ldots + b^{n-2} )}{n-1} \geq \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-2}\tag{2} \label{meq2}\end{equation}
Combining \eqref{meq} and \eqref{meq2}, we get
\begin{align}\dfrac{(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots + b^{n-1} )}{n} &=\dfrac{1}{n} \left(\frac{a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}}{2}\right)+A\\ &\ge \dfrac{1}{n} \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-1} +A \end{align}
where
\begin{align} A &= \dfrac{1}{n} \left(\dfrac{a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}}{2}+\dfrac{b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}a+\ldots+ba^{n-2}}{2}\right)\\
&\ge \dfrac{n-1}{n} \left(\dfrac{a}{2}\cdot \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-2} +\dfrac{b}{2} \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-2}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{n-1}{n}  \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-1}\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}\dfrac{(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots + b^{n-1} )}{n} &\ge\dfrac{1}{n} \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-1}+\dfrac{n-1}{n}  \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-1} \\&= \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-1}.\end{align}

$$2^{n-1}(a^n-b^n)/n(a-b) \geq (a+b)^{n-1}\iff \dfrac{a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots + b^{n-1} }{n} \geq \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n-1}.$$

Oops, silly mistakes. Thank you for pointing it out @Riemann. Luckily it is fixable.

@Tri Thanks so much for your great work. I have also proved it by The Mathematical Induction. However, I would like to find a more natural & elegant method.

@chrinide If you have proved it by Mathematical Induction, you should have stated that in the problem statement.  Instead, you said " I cannot find a good general way". If you were subsequently able to prove it, please edit the problem statement.

@CalvinLin Thanks so much for your kindly suggestion.
